# mysqli::prepare() vs mysqli_stmt::prepare()

Tags: php, mysqli

I was using the following code to make a query with prepared statements:
I used mysqli::prepare(), NOT mysqli_stmt::prepare(), so $res does not have to be initialized. It is returned by mysqli::prepared. [php.net link](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO best_scores(`user_id`, `test_id`, `score`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
if($res = $db->prepare($sql2) == FALSE) echo $db->error . "\n";
$res->bind_param("sii", $user_id, $_GET['test'], $max);
$res->execute();
$res->free_result();
```

When that code was reached, the following error appeared:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

I looked for answers but all the questions had mistakes in the SQL query string or they didn't free the previous results. None of them helped me, so I tried to change something. I changed my code into this:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO best_scores(`user_id`, `test_id`, `score`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$res = $db->stmt_init();
if($res->prepare($sql2) == FALSE) echo $db->error . "\n";
$res->bind_param("sii", $user_id, $_GET['test'], $max);
$res->execute();
$res->free_result();
```

Now it is working. But why is it different? What was the problem with the first attempt?

Edit: My $db object is defined like this:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Comment: can we see how your $db object is declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discuss it in the comments, it might be a wrong assignation in the `if()` block.

What do I tested. If block, like yours:

```
$x = (object)array('a'=>'b');

if ($a = $x == false) {
    echo 'a';
}

var_dump($a);
```

Output:

> boolean false

Then I have put parentheses around the assignation:

```
$x = (object)array('a'=>'b');


if (($a = $x) == false) {
    echo 'a';
}

var_dump($a);
```

Output:

> object(stdClass)[1]   public 'a' => string 'b' (length=1)

so you would need to put parentheses around the assignation for $res

```
if(($res = $db->prepare($sql2)) == FALSE)
```

Because your way, you wrongly reassign $res to `FALSE` and the object has been lost

Comment: You're right. I put the parentheses and the first version works. I also checked here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php, and the == operator has higher priority than =. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if your db->prepare worked in the first example and if it doesn't you use $res anyways, which is now not an object, because it wasn't initialized.
In the second example you declare and initialize it first.

Comment: It's true, but isn't the assignation done, no matter whether true/false `$res = ...` is

Comment: Where's the $db->stmt_init(); in the first example?

Comment: I was confused between http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php in the first one there was no need of `init`

Comment: There is no need for stmt_init(). The mysqli_stmt object is returned by mysqli::prepare().

Comment: @Sorin true, I first thought this, but then confused myself which one returns the actual needed object. However, after the `if()` statement, what does `var_dump($res)` saying? If the assignation in the `if` is done, maybe later the prepare fails, or not build the proper object

Comment: After the if statement, $res is FALSE. So the assignation is made and the problem seems to be from mysqli::prepare().

Comment: @Sorin I made a new answer about it. According to me, the problem is from the brackets around the assignation.

Answer (score 1):

In the Docs:

mysqli_stmt_init — Initializes a statement and returns an object for use with mysqli_stmt_prepare

in you prev code you do not have initialized. in second code snippet after initialization it worked.

Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php

Comment: He does have `$res = $db->prepare($sql2)` which according to prepare docs (`if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {`) is ok?

Comment: if you see this link on php site http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php they first have initialized. prepare is used after initialization.

Comment: Right, I did not see this at first time. Sorry about it

Comment: I was looking here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php where no need of `init` was mentioned

Comment: I did not use mysqli_stmt::prepare(), but mysqli::prepare(), which returns a mysqli_stmt object. This way, no initialization is needed. I edited the post and put a link there.

Comment: yes there is some difference between two links. one I mentioned and the one you mentioned.

Comment: @RoyalBg as Sorin said there is difference  between both.

Comment: Is there any chance the assignation to not be done inside the if. I just tested it, and there were no worries, but maybe it could depend on the PHP version?

Comment: both are available in PHP5. but one returns true or false so you need to check inside if for validation purpose. but in case ysqli::prepare(), which returns a mysqli_stmt object so do not use if

Comment: @MazIqbal you could look at my answer. I first thought it might not be assigned well, but when I tested various ways, it seemed like if there are no brackets around the assignation it returns boolean assignation

Comment: @RoyalBg oh yes i understood now the assignation. sorry  I did not got that before. yes you are correct

Comment: but need to make sure that what you written in you answer works in above situation.